# Modifying SlideMaster while in SlideShowMode: Textbox doesn't refresh

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a textbox in my Slide Master and I can change its text by `ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2).Shapes("C").TextFrame.TextRange = "sASfO"`

However, it doesn't work when it is in Slide Show Mode.
Although when I return back to Normal Mode, the text changes.

I tried refreshing the slide by using 
`Application.SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide Me.SlideIndex` but to no avail.

Going to the next slide and coming back to the previous slide doesn't "refresh" it either.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Previous
```

The only thing which works is exiting the Slide Show Mode and returning back to Slide Show Mode.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
```

There has to be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's is the normal operation of PowerPoint. Refreshing a presentation while it's running usually doesn't work. The only solution I'm aware of is this rather expensive add-in: https://www.presentationpoint.com/shop/datapoint/

Comment: Ouch. That sucks. Hopefully, some future updates might take care of this.
A user said that refreshing slides worked in PPT2010. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293286/why-does-a-countdown-timer-freeze-when-placed-in-slidemaster

Comment: As you suggest, things may have changed since earlier versions, but the trick to getting this to work used to be adding a shape to the slide before returning to it (ie, after going to .Next but before returning to .Previous in your example).  The shape can be off the slide and size doesn't seem to matter.  Give that a try, let us know if it still works and what version you're using it in.